# Product not adding to cart

Tags: cart, url, session

When opening up a product page (example.com/store/women/catalog/product/view/id/215/) in a new session and using the standard add to cart, my product gets dropped and says the shopping cart is empty. However, once a ?SID= is assigned I am able to add the product to the cart. I am using Lesti::FPC.

Form action before getting an SID:

> action="http://example.com/store/women/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3ByaW9yaXR5b3V0Zml0dGVyLmNvbS9zdG9yZS93b21lbi9jYXRhbG9nL3Byb2R1Y3Qvdmlldy9pZC8yMTUvP1NJRD1jYWUwNjU4ZWNiNjkxNTdjZDczMzZkNTllY2E0MmJmMg,,/product/215/form_key/Dij9pPXAwRBzAywH/?<(!)--
>   fpc session_id_placeholder -->"

Form action after getting an SID:

> action="http://example.com/store/women/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3ByaW9yaXR5b3V0Zml0dGVyLmNvbS9zdG9yZS93b21lbi9jYXRhbG9nL3Byb2R1Y3Qvdmlldy9pZC8yMTUvP1NJRD1jYWUwNjU4ZWNiNjkxNTdjZDczMzZkNTllY2E0MmJmMg,,/product/215/form_key/Dij9pPXAwRBzAywH/

They are the same besides the fpc session_id_placeholder

Comment: Are you able to fix this issue? if yes, then please post the solution.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the form key to the cart add link:

```
<?php

$formKey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();?>

<form action="/checkout/cart/add/product/<?php echo $productid; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $formKey; ?>" />

    <input type="text" name="qty"> QTY

    <input type="submit" value="Add to basket" />
</form>
```

Resource:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19999360/582138

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is what I actually need. I am linking to a product page: example.com/store/catalog/product/view/id/215/. When first time customers arrive here and click add to cart, the product gets dropped

Answer (score 1):

```
 <form action="<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"enctype="multipart/form-data">

         <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
           <input name="qty" value="  1" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" />
     <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add+')) ?>" onclick=" this.form.submit()" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" ><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add+') ?></span></span></button>

</form>

<?php 
  public function getAddUrl($product, $additional = array())
    {
      $routeParams = array(

            Mage_Core_Model_Url::FORM_KEY => $this->_getSingletonModel('core/session')->getFormKey()
        );


        return $this->_getUrl('checkout/cart/add', $routeParams);
    }

?>
```